# Logstash Tomcat logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I would like to Parse tomcat logs where we have soap/rest request and response. can any one give me any good example where we can parse those logs and save it in elastic search in json format.

Comment: Rather than make us lookup what a tomcat log might look like, why not post an example and tell us what trouble you're having in parsing it based on the 72,500 results returned by google.

Comment: Depends of the technologies that you want to use, you can do in scala or via command shell in linux... there are infinite options to do. First create an index, then populate the index and use kibana for representation. Yo can read a lot ot guides in a lot of places.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Allen for your response. Here is my example which I am trying to parse using `Grok Pattern`. I am new to this one so trying to figure it out whether this one is right approach or not.

> 2015-09-28 10:50:30,249 {http-apr-8080-exec-4} INFO [org.apache.cxf.services.interfaceType] 1.0.0-LOCAL - Inbound Message
>   ID: 1
>   Address: http://localhost:8080/interface/interface?wsdl
>   Encoding: UTF-8
>   Http-Method: POST
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
>   Headers: {Accept=[*/*], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[2871], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], host=[localhost:8080], pragma=[no-cache], SOAPAction=["http://services.localhost.com/calculate"], user-agent=[Apache CXF 2.7.5]}
>   Payload: users_19911111test123456false

Answer (score 0):

```
filter {
if [type] == "tomcatlog"{
   multiline {
       #type => "all" # no type means for all inputs
       pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
       negate => true
       what => "previous"
       }
   grok {
        match => {
        message => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}\{(?<thread>[^)]+)\}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}\[(?<logger>[^\]]+)\]%{SPACE}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
        }
        }
        date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
            remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
    }
   }
}
```

Use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to create `grok` filters. Useful pattern are listed [patterns](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.